# Why is InterstitialAd not loaded after the first trigger?

Tags: react-native, admob

I manage to get the first ad to show, but app crashed the next time I try to trigger an ad. And gives me this error: `Error: InterstitialAd.show() The requested InterstitialAd has not loaded and could not be shown`

In App.js

```
componentDidMount() {
    const eventListener = interstitial.onAdEvent(type => {
      if (type === AdEventType.LOADED) {
        this.setState({
          setLoaded: true,
        });
      }
    });

    interstitial.load();
    eventListener();

  }

showAds = () => {
    interstitial.show();
    // No advert ready to show yet
    if (!this.state.loaded) {
      console.log('null');
      return null;
    }
  };

// This trigger is within another function
      this.showAds();
```

I have a class component so I use ComponentDidMount instead of useEffect. Might that cause some troubles?

UPDATE:

```
    this.state = {
      loaded: false,
      setLoaded: false,
      Listener: null,
    };
```

The above state is an attempt to redo

```
const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
```

Comment: you have to trigger show only when there is an ad so place the .show() inside else of
if (!this.state.loaded) {
      console.log('null');
      return null;
    }else{
interstitial.show();
}

Comment: Actually that shows me no ads at all

Comment: ok you are removing the eventListener immediately after mounting you have to call it in `componentWillUnmount()` i will write snippet  as answer

Comment: If it helps, this is the guide I'm following but tried to change useEffect to ComponentDidMount since I have a class component: https://docs.page/invertase/react-native-google-ads/displaying-ads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
constructor () {
    super();
    this.Listener=null
  }

componentDidMount() {
    this.Listener = interstitial.onAdEvent(type => {
      if (type === AdEventType.LOADED) {
        this.setState({
          loaded: true,
        });
      }else if(type === AdEventType.CLOSED){
        this.loadAd()
     }
    });
    this.loadAd()
 }

componentWillUnmount(){
  if(this.Listener!==null){
   this.Listener()
  }
}

loadAd = () =>{
   this.setState({
      loaded: false,
   });
   interstitial.load();
}

showAds = () => {
   if (!this.state.loaded) {
     console.log('null');
     return null;
   }else{
     interstitial.show();  
   }
 };
```

Comment: I still get no ads at all. I get the log `null` every time showAds get's triggered (I got this before as well when the first ad was working but then it crashed)

Comment: I updated my code above to show the state, which is why it goes into `null`, but wouldn't it be same as the useState example (also shown above)?

Comment: if its happening on the second time you have to reset state i have updated code to handle the next ad load hope it works for you

Comment: It still behaves the same. No ads and null in log.

Comment: are you using test ad ids or actual ad ids?

Comment: I'm using test ad ids ```const interstitial = InterstitialAd.createForAdRequest(TestIds.INTERSTITIAL, {
  requestNonPersonalizedAdsOnly: true,
});```

Comment: i could suggest see if ad loaded event is getting triggered by doing a console ` this.Listener = interstitial.onAdEvent(type => { console.log("ad event type",type) ...`

Comment: I actually just did a console on top of componentDidMount and it only triggered once, in the beginning. And the same with your console on type. Shouldn't it trigger it every time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241760/discussion-between-dheeraj-and-jossif-elefteriadis).